# Show the direction of one-way roads

Tags: cities-skylines

In *Cities: Skylines*, how do I easily show the direction of one-way roads?

When I'm building a city and I want to use one-way roads, it's hard to spot from a distance what direction a road is going, unless I zoom in until I can see the arrows on the actual road itself. Or if I pay attention to the flow of traffic, if there even is any traffic on the road.

SimCity [clearly indicates](http://www.wiki.sc4devotion.com/images/thumb/f/fb/OWR3.jpg/400px-OWR3.jpg) the direction of one-way roads, for instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet may be to look for the tiny arrows near intersections. It really does pay to zoom in a little and it depends on how good your eyes are.

[image: Oneways]

Comment: I am disappointed. Why no hand drawn circles?

Comment: I guess I am lazy after all :)

Comment: I thought freehand circles were only mandatory on Stack Overflow?